# Deserialization Problem

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер, serialize

Подскажите у меня exception(End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed) при десериализации объекта в клиент-серверном приложении на сервере. Клиент:

```
     private void Send(Socket client)
    {
        byte[] buffer;
        fileDetails = new FileDetails();
        using (_memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (Stream fs = new FileStream(textBox1.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
            {
                fs.Read(fileDetails.buffer, 0, fileDetails.buffer.Length);
                // считывается имя с TextBoxa
                string[] temp = textBox1.Text.Split('\\');
                string[] temp2 = temp[temp.Length - 1].Split('.');
                fileDetails.fileName = temp2[0];
                fileDetails.fileType = temp2[1];

                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                formatter.Serialize(_memoryStream, fileDetails);


            }
        }
        buffer = _memoryStream.ToArray();

        client.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);


    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            handler.EndSend(ar);

            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Сервер:

```
     private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Signal the main thread to continue.
    allDone.Set();

    // Get the socket that handles the client request.
    listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
    handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
    // Create the state object.
    buffer = new byte[1024];
    handler.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), listener);
}

private static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Signal the main thread to continue.
    allDone.Set();

    listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;

    fileDet = new FileDetails();

    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
    if (bytesRead == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        using (_memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            _memoryStream.Seek(0, 0); // не помогает 
            //_memoryStream.Flush тоже

            BinaryFormatter fileFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            fileDet = (FileDetails) fileFormatter.Deserialize(_memoryStream);

            string fileName = fileDet.fileName + "." + fileDet.fileType;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                fs.Write(fileDet.buffer, 0, fileDet.buffer.Length);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Not all data received. Get more.
        handler.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), listener);
    }
}
```

Объект который хочу десериализовать(находиться в отдельной сборке):

```
    [Serializable]
  public class FileDetails
 {
private string _fileName;
private string _fileType;

public string fileName
{
    get { return _fileName; }
    set { _fileName = value; }
}


public string fileType
{
    get { return _fileType; }
    set { _fileType = value; }
}


public byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
```

Comment: 1. `_memoryStream.ToArray() `  записано вне `using` - так делать нельзя.

Comment: 2. Опять пишу `MemoryStream(buffer)` исправить на `MemoryStream(buffer,0,bytesRead )`

Comment: _memoryStream.ToArray() записано вне using - так делать нельзяОпять пишу MemoryStream(buffer) исправить на MemoryStream(buffer,0,bytesRead ) @nick_n_a Сделал не помогает.

Comment: И `buffer` и там (сервер) и там (клиент) содержит одинаковые байты что видно в дебаггере?

Comment: Спасибо. Проверил действительно я при создании буфера неккоректно указал размер. +1 к карме))))

Comment: @goodwin8137 не забыавйте, что то, что вы отправили с клиента одним вызовом Save, не обязательно придет на сервер одним куском. BeginReceive вычитываетне столько байт, сколько ему скажут, а столько, сколько успело дойти. Если нужно вычитать ровно N байт - нужно исплользовать NetworkStream. И сериализовать/десериализовать можно прямо в него/из него.

Comment: @PashaPash Что означает с одним вызовом Save?

Comment: Означает что при задержке, свичи/хабы могут ваш пакет разбить на 2 и более куска, в плоть до такого числа - сколько у вас байт. Например кусок в 300 байт может в ReadCallback прийти как 256 байт, а второй раз в 44 байта (256+44 = 300). Поэтому в протоколах верхнего уровня часто используются довески в заголовке указывающие длинну пакета или метки конца, в HTTP это Content-Length.

Comment: @goodwin8137 Send, а не Save. Опечатался :)

Comment: @PashaPash Спасибо учту на будущее)